# Which meaning of 'stall' in pedestal?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I recognise that etymology question are discouraged here, but I'm only asking about English herein.

> [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pedestal&searchmode=none): 1560s, "base supporting a column, statue, etc.," from Middle French piédestal (1540s), from Italian piedistallo "base of a pillar," from **pie** "foot" + **di** "of" + **stallo** "stall, place, seat," from a Germanic source (see **[stall](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stall&allowed_in_frame=0)** (n.1)).

My English is very basic, so I don't understand all those explanations in the link for **stall**. Which modern definition of [stall](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stall) fits? How do you determine/deduce this? Please explain the steps or thought processes; I’d like to try to resolve this myself in the future?

Comment: Just as your character sheds no light on your great-grandfather's character, modern senses of a word shed no light on the meaning of its ancestor.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks what  modern sense of a word defines its 16th century meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Stall" at one time was basically a synonym for "place". I do not believe the modern definition of stall is what they are getting at here. In modern English, stall has a much more limited meaning - we talk of stalls (the place where you pen an animal in a barn) or stalls in a parking lot (the space between the lines where you park your car). Neither of those fit the usage above, of course.